# Fill gaps in SQL Server dates ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

In SQL Server 2014 I have a `Periods` table that looks like the following:

```
| PeriodId | PeriodStart | PeriodEnd  |
---------------------------------------
| 202005   | 2020-05-01  | 2020-05-31 |
| 202006   | 2020-06-01  | 2020-06-30 |
```

A period won't always be from the first to the last day of the month.

Then I have an `Activities` table, which has some activities the user has programmed:

```
| ActivityId | UserId | ActivityStart | ActivityEnd |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1          | A      | 2020-05-20    | 2020-06-05  |
| 2          | A      | 2020-06-15    | 2020-06-18  |
| 3          | B      | 2020-06-10    | 2020-06-25  |
```

There can be gaps between the activities of a user, but the same user will never have overlaping activities.

Now I need a query that limits the activities dates ranges to the start and end of the period, and fills the gaps to complete the period. I'll always filter by `PeriodId`, so I'll just put the example result for `PeriodId = 202006`:

```
| PeriodId | UserId | ActivityId | NewActivityStart | NewActivityEnd |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 202006   | A      | 1          | 2020-06-01       | 2020-06-05     |  --Part of ActivityId 1
| 202006   | A      | NULL       | 2020-06-06       | 2020-06-14     |  --Fill between activities 1 and 2
| 202006   | A      | 2          | 2020-06-15       | 2020-06-18     |
| 202006   | A      | NULL       | 2020-06-19       | 2020-06-30     |  --Fill until end of period
| 202006   | B      | NULL       | 2020-06-01       | 2020-06-09     |  --Fill from start of period
| 202006   | B      | 3          | 2020-06-10       | 2020-06-25     |
| 202006   | B      | NULL       | 2020-06-26       | 2020-06-30     |  --Fill until end of period
```

I've been able to contain the activity dates within the period with the following query:

```
SELECT p.PeriodId, a.UserId, a.ActivityId
       IIF(p.PeriodStart > a.ActivityStart, p.PeriodStart, a.ActivityStart) AS NewActivityStart,
       IIF(p.PeriodEnd < a.ActivityEnd, p.PeriodEnd, a.ActivityEnd) AS NewActivityEnd
FROM Periods p
JOIN Activities a ON a.ActivityStart <= p.PeriodEnd AND a.ActivityEnd >= p.PeriodStart
```

But I haven't been able to fill the gaps in the ranges. I've tried with a correlative dates table and/or with Window Functions like LAG/LEAD.

I feel like Window Functions could be the solution, and I've tried to follow [examples](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9130/sql-server-window-functions-gaps-and-islands-problem/) about gaps/islands, but I just haven't been able to understand them well enough to make it work.

Is there a way to complete the query to fill the missing gaps? Are there other ways to achieve this in a query?

Comment: ideally, you need a calendar table. which will help in easily generating these kinds of results

Comment: @VenkataramanR I've tried with a numbers table, by adding them to the `PeriodStart` column, like `dateadd(day, cn.Number, p.PeriodStart)`, but I haven't figured out how to correctly use the Window Functions to go from that to filling the gaps.

Comment: There is a typo in your desired results, I think, the second last row should have ActivityId = 3, not 2.

Comment: Why would you want results to the "end of the month" rather than the end of each period?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the Id and month/period typos

Comment: @VenkataramanR - You should post your Calendar Table solution. :D

Comment: @JeffModen,agree with you. as it was comments, I just gave comment. I could not spend time at that time to give the exact answer to this question. :)

Comment: @VenkataramanR - That's a shame.  I think it would be a valuable addition to this thread.  Except for holiday calculations, I generally avoid Calendar tables but would have loved to see a solution that uses one.  Totally understood about not having the time, though.

Comment: @JeffModen, I would wok on a solution and update the thread. thanks for your motivation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is that complicated.  If you expand the periods into individual dates and do a `left join`, then this becomes a gaps-and-islands problem:

```
with dates as (
      select periodid, periodstart as dte, periodend
      from periods
      union all
      select periodid, dateadd(day, 1, dte), periodend
      from dates
      where dte < periodend
     )
select userid, activityid, min(dte), max(dte)
from (select d.dte, d.periodid, u.userid, a.activityid,
             row_number() over (partition by u.userid, a.activityid order by d.dte) as seqnum
      from dates d cross join
           (select distinct userid from activities) u left join
           activities a
           on a.userid = u.userid and
              a.activitystart <= d.dte and a.activityend >= d.dte
     ) da
group by userid, activityid, periodid, dateadd(day, -seqnum, dte)
order by userid, min(dte);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d0ae07624e3cefc9088cac68b00d6baa) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  This produces results for all users and all periods -- which seems reasonable given your description.  It is pretty simple to modify to filter out users with no activity during a given period.

Also, this does not go to the end of the month.  Instead, it includes the complete periods.  I don't see why months would play into this -- except to confuse matters -- consider if two periods have days in the same month, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the month/period typo. I checked the fiddle results, but it's mixing the activities periods from different users. For example, user B should have only 3 "final" date ranges (looking just at june): 1st to 9th (filler), 10th to 25th (activity) and 26th to 30th (filler), but it's mixing them with the ranges from activities from user A.

Comment: @FercoCQ . . . Oops, the code was missing the join condition on users.  It is fixed.

Comment: @FercoCQ . . . I laugh a little now at the second sentence.  Obviously the `left join` was too complicated for me in my first attempt.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this using various techniques. In the example below, I am using an approach as the code is a body of SQL routine.

So, here is your date:

```
DECLARE @Periods TABLE
(
    [PeriodId] INT
   ,[PeriodStart] DATE
   ,[PeriodEnd] DATE
);

INSERT INTO @Periods ([PeriodId], [PeriodStart], [PeriodEnd])
VALUES ('202005', '2020-05-01', '2020-05-31')
      ,('202006', '2020-06-01', '2020-06-30');

DECLARE @Activities  TABLE
(
    [ActivityId] INT
   ,[UserId] CHAR(1)
   ,[ActivityStart] DATE
   ,[ActivityEnd] DATE
);

INSERT INTO @Activities ([ActivityId], [UserId], [ActivityStart], [ActivityEnd])
VALUES (1, 'A', '2020-05-20', '2020-06-05')
      ,(2, 'A', '2020-06-15', '2020-06-18')
      ,(3, 'B', '2020-06-10', '2020-06-25');
```

Then, let's say we have an input parameter `@PeriodID` and via it we are extracting the corresponding start and end date periods:

```
DECLARE @PeriodID INT
       ,@PeriodDateStart DATE
       ,@PeriodDateEnd DATE;

SET @PeriodID = 202006;

SELECT @PeriodDateStart = [PeriodStart]
      ,@PeriodDateEnd = [PeriodEnd]
FROM @Periods 
WHERE [PeriodId] = @PeriodID;
```

Then, let's create a buffer table in which we will calculated the matches between the `activity` and the `period` table and add `start` and `end` periods records if needed:

```
DECLARE @Buffer TABLE
(
    [ActivityId] INT
   ,[UserId] CHAR(1)
   ,[ActivityStart] DATE
   ,[ActivityEnd] DATE
);

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT A.[ActivityId]
          ,A.[UserId]
          ,A.[ActivityStart]
          ,A.[ActivityEnd]
    FROM @Activities A
    INNER JOIN @Periods P
        ON A.[ActivityStart] <= P.[PeriodEnd]
        AND A.[ActivityEnd] >= P.[PeriodStart]
    WHERE P.PeriodId = @PeriodID
)
INSERT INTO @Buffer ([ActivityId], [UserId], [ActivityStart], [ActivityEnd])
SELECT [ActivityId]
      ,[UserId]
      ,IIF([ActivityStart] < @PeriodDateStart, @PeriodDateStart, [ActivityStart]) AS [ActivityStart]
      ,[ActivityEnd]
FROM DataSource 
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL
      ,[UserId]
      ,DATEADD(DAY, 1, MAX([ActivityEnd]))
      ,@PeriodDateEnd
FROM DataSource
GROUP BY [UserId]
HAVING DATEADD(DAY, 1, MAX([ActivityEnd])) < @PeriodDateEnd
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL
      ,[UserId]
      ,@PeriodDateStart
      ,DATEADD(DAY, -1, MIN([ActivityStart]))
FROM DataSource
GROUP BY [UserId]
HAVING DATEADD(DAY, -1, MIN([ActivityStart])) > @PeriodDateStart;
```

[image]

It's simple. In the common table expression I have used your code. And then, we just simply check if we need to add a record before or/and after the period for a specific user.

Now, we are ready to calculate the gaps, right? A lot of variants here. I am using the `LEAD` function in order to calculate the `missing` period for each row. The statement is below:

```
SELECT *
      ,DATEADD(DAY, 1, [ActivityEnd]) AS [MissingPeriodStart]
      ,DATEADD(DAY, -1, LEAD([ActivityStart]) OVER (PARTITION BY [UserID] ORDER BY [ActivityStart] ASC)) AS [MissingPeriodEnd]
FROM @Buffer
ORDER BY USERID, ActivityStart;
```

The output is like this:

[image]

So, you may see how we have generated `missing periods` dates for each row, except the last one. Now, we need to get only some of these `missing periods`. It's like this:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,DATEADD(DAY, 1, [ActivityEnd]) AS [MissingPeriodStart]
          ,DATEADD(DAY, -1, LEAD([ActivityStart]) OVER (PARTITION BY [UserID] ORDER BY [ActivityStart] ASC)) AS [MissingPeriodEnd]
    FROM @Buffer
)
SELECT @PeriodID AS [PeriodID]
      ,[UserId]
      ,[ActivityId]
      ,[ActivityStart]
      ,[ActivityEnd]
FROM DataSource
UNION ALL 
SELECT @PeriodID AS [PeriodID]
      ,[UserId]
      ,NULL
      ,[MissingPeriodStart]
      ,[MissingPeriodEnd]
FROM DataSource
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM DataSource DS
    WHERE [MissingPeriodStart] = DS.[ActivityStart]
        AND [UserID] = DS.[UserID]
)
    AND [MissingPeriodStart] < [MissingPeriodEnd]
ORDER BY [UserId]
        ,[ActivityStart];
```

and the result is:

[image]

Of course, this is an idea. You may need to change it or tune it in order to be used with your real data. I hope it will give you a start.

Comment: Thanks! Really complete answer. The complexity of the answers have certainly made me question whether I should do this in a query or as a pre-process, but at the moment, and as stated in the question, I'm looking to achieve this in a query.

Comment: @FercoCQ You can easily replace the table_variable with CTE expressions if you need.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the craziest gaps problem I've seen, but it's a good one.

```
DECLARE @PeriodId int = 202006;

DECLARE @ps date, @pe date;
SELECT @ps = PeriodStart, @pe = PeriodEnd FROM dbo.Periods
   WHERE PeriodId = @PeriodId;
   
;WITH dates(rn,dt) AS 
(
    SELECT 1, @ps UNION ALL SELECT rn + 1, DATEADD(DAY, rn, @ps) 
    FROM dates WHERE dt < @pe
)
groups(UserId, dt, ActivityId, grp) AS
(
  SELECT u.UserId, d.dt, r.ActivityId, 
    d.rn - DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY u.UserId, r.ActivityStart ORDER BY d.dt)
  FROM dates AS d CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT UserId FROM dbo.Activities 
    WHERE @pe >= ActivityStart AND @ps <= ActivityEnd) AS u
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Activities AS r
  ON u.UserId = r.UserId AND d.dt >= r.ActivityStart AND d.dt <= r.ActivityEnd
)
SELECT PeriodId = @PeriodId, UserId, ActivityId,
  NewActivityStart = MIN(dt),
  NewActivityEnd   = MAX(dt)
FROM groups 
GROUP BY UserId, ActivityId, grp
ORDER BY UserId, NewActivityStart;
```

If a period can be over 100 days, you need `MAXRECURSION` at the end:

```
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);
```

If a period can be more than 32,767 days, change `32767` to `0`.

Updated fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=93ee4188699024941801b30fec304839).