# Generate missing non-contiguous date ranges

Tags: t-sql

I have the following example dataset (actual table is about 30000 rows).

[image: Data]

I need to scan through the table and identify any non-contiguous dates for all references within the table that have non-contiguous data, and generate data to fill in the missing dates

So for the above reference I would need example data generated to be in bold below (showing existing rows for clarity):

| ID | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7172 | 2020-03-13 | 2020-10-22 |
| 7172 | 2020-10-23 | 2020-11-08 |
| **7172** | **2020-11-09** | **2020-11-09** |
| 7172 | 2020-11-10 | 2020-11-19 |
| **7172** | **2020-11-20** | **2020-11-20** |
| 7172 | 2020-11-21 | 2021-03-14 |
| 7172 | 2021-03-15 | 2021-03-17 |
| **7172** | **2021-03-18** | **2021-03-19** |
| 7172 | 2021-03-20 | 2021-03-28 |
| 7172 | 2021-03-29 | 2021-04-25 |
| **7172** | **2021-04-26** | **2021-30-04** |
| 7172 | 2021-05-01 | 2021-06-07 |
| **7172** | **2021-06-08** | **2021-06-08** |
| 7172 | 2021-06-09 | 2022-01-09 |

Can anyone help please?

Comment: [Here's an accepted answer to the same kind of question. Gaps and islands problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63412788/3585500)

Comment: When you searched for [`[tsql] missing dates`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btsql%5D+missing+dates) did you find anything useful?

Comment: "I have"/"I need"/"Can anyone help please?" doesn't show the [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) expected. Rather than immediately vote-to-close I thought a pointer might help. I've been wrong, frequently, before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2021-30-04 is a bad date (hehe).

I took your table and used it to generate a table variable, and added a couple of rows:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID INT, START_DATE DATE, END_DATE DATE)
INSERT INTO @TABLE (ID, START_DATE, END_DATE) VALUES
(7172, '2020-03-13', '2020-10-22'), (7172, '2020-10-23', '2020-11-08'),
(7172, '2020-11-10', '2020-11-19'), (7172, '2020-11-20', '2020-11-20'),
(7172, '2020-11-21', '2021-03-14'), (7172, '2021-03-15', '2021-03-17'),
(7172, '2021-03-20', '2021-03-28'), (7172, '2021-03-29', '2021-04-25'),
(7172, '2021-05-01', '2021-06-07'), (7172, '2021-06-09', '2022-01-09'),
(1234, '2020-03-13', '2022-03-15'), (1234, '2022-03-20', '2022-03-25');
```

If I understand correctly, we'd be looking to generate rows:

```
--(7172, '2020-11-09', '2020-11-09'),
--(7172, '2021-03-18', '2021-03-19'),
--(7172, '2021-04-26', '2021-03-04'),
--(7172, '2021-06-08', '2021-06-08'),
--(1234, '2022-03-16', '2022-03-19'),
```

I poked at this some, and got the result you're looking for using some recursive CTE voodoo. I can't promise this is going to be performant, but it might be a good starting point:

```
DECLARE @MaxDate DATE = (SELECT MAX(END_DATE) FROM @TABLE)

;WITH DateRange AS (
SELECT ID, MIN(END_DATE) AS Date FROM @TABLE GROUP BY ID--@MinDate AS Date
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, DATEADD(DAY,1,Date)
  FROM DateRange
 WHERE Date < @MaxDate
), MissingDates AS (
SELECT dr.ID, dr.Date, t.START_DATE, t.END_DATE
  FROM DateRange dr
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @TABLE t
      ON dr.Date BETWEEN t.START_DATE AND t.END_DATE
      AND dr.ID = t.ID
 WHERE t.ID IS NULL  
), ranges AS (
SELECT s.ID, s.date AS START_DATE, s.date AS END_DATE, DATEADD(DAY,1,s.Date) AS NEXT_DATE
  FROM MissingDates s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MissingDates n
      ON s.Date = DATEADD(DAY,1,n.Date)
      AND s.ID = n.ID
 WHERE n.Date IS NULL   
UNION ALL
SELECT a.ID, a.START_DATE, r.Date AS END_DATE, DATEADD(DAY,1,r.Date) AS NEXT_DATE
  FROM ranges a
    INNER JOIN MissingDates r
      ON a.NEXT_DATE = r.Date
      AND a.ID = r.ID
)
SELECT ID AS ID, START_DATE, MAX(END_DATE) AS END_DATE
  FROM ranges
 GROUP BY ID, START_DATE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

```
ID      START_DATE  END_DATE
----------------------------
7172    2020-11-09  2020-11-09
7172    2021-03-18  2021-03-19
7172    2021-04-26  2021-04-30
7172    2021-06-08  2021-06-08
7172    2022-01-10  2022-03-25
1234    2022-03-16  2022-03-19
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect - working a treat. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can make life a bit easier on respondents by making "Readily Consumable" Test Data, like the following example... (I added in the extra ID that @PatrickHurst did)...

```
--===== Create and populate the test table with the given test data.
     -- This is NOT a part of the solution.
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Test;
GO
 CREATE TABLE #Test 
        (
         ID INT
        , START_DATE DATE
        , END_DATE DATE
        )
;
INSERT INTO #Test (ID, START_DATE, END_DATE) VALUES
   (7172,'2020-03-13','2020-10-22')
  ,(7172,'2020-10-23','2020-11-08')
--,(7172,'2020-11-09','2020-11-09') --Is Missing
  ,(7172,'2020-11-10','2020-11-19')
--,(7172,'2020-11-20','2020-11-20') --Is Missing
  ,(7172,'2020-11-21','2021-03-14')
  ,(7172,'2021-03-15','2021-03-17')
--,(7172,'2021-03-18','2021-03-19') --Is Missing
  ,(7172,'2021-03-20','2021-03-28')
  ,(7172,'2021-03-29','2021-04-25')
--,(7172,'2021-04-26','2021-04-30') --Is Missing (And you had a bad date here)
  ,(7172,'2021-05-01','2021-06-07')
--,(7172,'2021-06-08','2021-06-08') --Is Missing
  ,(7172,'2021-06-09','2022-01-09')
  ,(1234,'2020-03-13','2022-03-15')
  ,(1234,'2022-03-20','2022-03-25')
;
```

If you have SQL Server 2012 or above, LAG makes this easy (and someone can probably simplify it even more)...

```
   WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT  *
        ,mSTART_DATE = LAG(DATEADD(dd,1,END_DATE),1,START_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY START_DATE)
        ,mEND_DATE   = DATEADD(dd,-1,START_DATE)
   FROM #Test
)
--===== Finds the existing date ranges
 SELECT ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, Comment = '' FROM #Test
  UNION ALL
--===== Finds the missing date ranges
 SELECT ID,mSTART_DATE,mEND_DATE, Comment = 'Was Missing' FROM cte WHERE mSTART_DATE <> START_DATE
  ORDER BY ID, START_DATE
;
```

Here are the results...

[image]

If you truly only want the missing date ranges, then the following does it...

```
   WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT  *
        ,mSTART_DATE = LAG(DATEADD(dd,1,END_DATE),1,START_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY START_DATE)
        ,mEND_DATE   = DATEADD(dd,-1,START_DATE)
   FROM #Test
)
 SELECT ID,START_DATE = mSTART_DATE,END_DATE = mEND_DATE FROM cte WHERE mSTART_DATE <> START_DATE
  ORDER BY ID,START_DATE
;
```

Results:

[image]